# Mongoose Query for Boolean field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

To query for Boolean field, I have to use "false" instead of false.
I am using Mongoose with Node JS.

Mongodb Schema Definition:

```
var MySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    isPrivate: { type: Boolean, default: false }
})
db.model('MyModel', MySchema);
```

Query:

```
MyModel.find({ isPrivate: false })
```

The above query doesn't return any dataset while the below code does.

```
MyModel.find({ isPrivate: "false" })
```

Please help.

Comment: Help with what exactly?  You have a working solution.

Comment: Is Boolean value supposed to be compared as String?

Comment: Can you enable debugging by adding `mongoose.set('debug', true);` to your code and see what query is being generated? Those two Mongoose queries should result in the same native queries due to the schema-based casting.

Comment: They generate the exact same native queries. I solved the problem by adding isPrivate field to every existing documents. I changed my Schema recently by adding the property and forgot to update documents. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

As per your model you should first update your documents to change `"false"` to `false` using update method like this :

```
MyModel.update({},{"$set":{"isPrivate":false}},{ multi: true })
```

If you are not comfortable to update documents then you should used `$or or $in` like this

```
MyModel.find({ $or:[ {'isPrivate':"false"}, {'isPrivate':false} ]})

MyModel.find({ "isPrivate": { "$in": ["false",false] } })
```

Comment: It was my mistake. Those queries I mentioned generate the same results. I solved the problem by adding isPrivate field to every existing documents. I changed my Schema recently by adding the property and forgot to update documents. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you updated your schema by adding a new path and created new documents with this new schema and store in collection that has old documents created with the old schema, you will face this problem. In my case, i added the boolean path `rated` with "default":false to my `jobs` collection that already had documents without this field. when i made a find query below

```
Job.find({rated: false}, cb)
```

the query returned an empty cursor even though there were jobs with `rated: false`.

I only solved the problem by jumping to the console and updating all jobs documents with field `rated` with default value `false`. After that my queries returned cursors that were consistent with the database.